Windows software to merge videos
As online websites don't respect privacy, I don't want to use them to merge videos.
I want a simple lightweight fast software that can easily merge 2 or more videos and give the best output.
I have already tried openshot and shotcut but there are few issues.

I have to manually choose the output dimensions and even choose the output quality %.
After opening videos I have to drag them to timeline and merge them which is issue.
I have to manually choose aspect ratio. Which I don't know how to do. For example, if 1st video is 360x480 and second video is 644x720. Then what should be output resolution?
If I mess with sequence of videos in the timeline then I have to delete whole timeline and start again.

I know these things are not a big issue for someone who uses these kind of software regularly but as I am new so I want something simple.
What I want:

Simple drag and drop
Ability to put something like part1, part2 after one video ends.
Automatically chooses the best aspect ratio, that will not let video quality deteriorate.
Fast

I want something as simple as these kind of websites can do.

https://clideo.com/merge-video

https://online-video-cutter.com/merge-videos


